# Derivatives of laplacian on sphere

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, linear-pde

Let $f$ be a function defined on the unit sphere $S^2$ parametrized by $(\theta, \phi)$ (as in spherical coordinates).

Is it true that
$$\frac{\partial \Delta u}{\partial \theta}=\Delta\frac{\partial  u}{\partial \theta}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial \Delta u}{\partial \phi}=\Delta\frac{\partial  u}{\partial \phi}?$$
In other words, does laplacian commute with partial derivatives with respect to $\theta$ and $\phi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laplacian operator $\Delta$ in the coordinate can be tas:
$$
\Delta u = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} ) + \frac{1}{r^2 \sin^2\phi}  \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial \theta ^2 } + \frac{1}{r^2 \sin\phi}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} ( \sin \phi \frac{\partial u}{\partial \phi}).
$$
in case of $u(r,\phi,\theta)=u(\phi,\theta)$, and $r=1$ you get:
$$
\Delta u = \frac{1}{ \sin^2\phi}  \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial \theta ^2 } + \frac{1}{ \sin\phi}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} ( \sin \phi \frac{\partial u}{\partial \phi}).
$$
as you can see coefficients of partial derivatives are functions of $\phi$ so they cannot commute with its partial derivatives respect to this variable. for example:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \bigg( \frac{1}{ \sin^2\phi}  \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial \theta ^2 } \bigg) \neq \frac{1}{ \sin^2\phi} \frac{\partial ^2 }{\partial \theta ^2 } \bigg(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \phi} \bigg)
$$
but they are not function of $\theta$. so with some assumption of continuity of $u$ for change the order of derivatives, you can change Laplacian with partial derivative respect to $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you so much.